# Create Role in WP from Group in CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, groups, roles

In WP 5.5/CiviCRM 5.29 I have only one membership type at the organization level and 2 groups of beneficiaries depending on some criteria. I have all the needed extensions from Christian Wach.

I need to synchronize the groups into WP Roles and not groups in order to let them access to personalized content defined with Elementor.

It seems that this is not yet possible but maybe I'm wrong.

Does anyone know about this setting?

Answer (score 2):

You can go one better than syncing to roles using the [CiviCRM Groups Sync](https://develop.tadpole.cc/plugins/civicrm-groups-sync) plugin instead. It keeps Contacts in CiviCRM Groups in sync with WordPress Users in groups provided by the [Groups plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/). That way you are free to adjust your users' roles without affecting the sets of permissions that they have which are related to CiviCRM or member-only content.

Comment: Thanks Christian for your work. If I understood properly, I should first create the group from within WP Groups plugin and it will automatically and immediately create the new group in CiviCRM, isn't ?

Comment: Either way will do - there's also an option in the CiviCRM "New Group" form called "Create Synced Group" which will create the synced group in Groups.